# wpf Control Template not working at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

After creating ControlTemplate for Wpf window it's working fine in design view. But when I run, it does not show the outer red border.

here is my code

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">

                    <Border Padding="20" Background="red">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome
        ResizeBorderThickness="10"
        CaptionHeight="40"
        CornerRadius="0"
        GlassFrameThickness="0"
        />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<Grid>
    <Border Background="Black" Padding="20">
        <Button Content="ok"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

The outer red border not showing when I run it. Can anyone tell me if I made any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, your window's type is `MainWindow`, not `Window`, hence the Style does not apply.

You may change the Style's `TargetType` to MainWindow:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

Or set the Window's `Style` property directly:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    ...
</Window>
```

Or set only the `Template` property directly:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
            <Border Padding="20" Background="red">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand from your simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Just making small change it worked fine for me

```
 <Window.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">
             <Setter Property="Template">
                ...
         </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Not working with only local:mainwindow because I need to add xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" in window section.

Comment: Yes you need to add this name space, in my case its xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1".